# open clip board failed when generating step definition

Tags: specflow

I upgraded visual studio to vs2022 and installed spec flow extension for visual studio 2022. When I click on a step in feature file and then go to step definition, a dialog box opens. When I click ok button an error is shown.

> error message : OpenClipboard Failed

[image]

Comment: Have you restarted Visual Studio since installing the SpecFlow extension?

Comment: yes .still I see the error

Comment: I wonder if the upgrade to VS 2022 has caused some problems. If you are on Windows, try repairing the Visual Studio installation. If that doesn't work, you might need to uninstall Visual Studio and reinstall it.